# How can I update a session after an Ajax call?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My application makes a lot of requests to an API controller. The problem I am running into is that my APIController has no access to the current session (which - it shouldn't). But since the calls are made via javascript after the page loads - I don't know how to tell my app to update the session.

What is the accepted way to handle changes to session values after receiving updated data from an ajax call?

Example:

```
public static class SessionManager
{
    public static User CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            return (User)HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"];
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"] = value;
        }
    }
}

public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage DeleteSomething(SomeModel model)
    {
        // Do work
    }
}
```

**then in the view**

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'DELETE',
     url: '{PATH TO API}',
     data: { the data },
     traditional: true,
     success: function (response) {
         // Now I need to update the user stored in the session
         // How do I do that?
     } else {
     }
});
```

Comment: Why can't you use HttpContext.Current.Session like you do in your SessionManager?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat I tried that - but it doesn't seem to work. I added a breakpoint and "CurrentUaer" seems to be null when referenced from an API controller.

Comment: Can you access the `User` property and use built-in security?  You could store your `User` object in the HttpCache by user name instead of in the session...

Comment: @JasonGoemaat: This is a Web API. It's *stateless*. No session, no cache. Each request is just as if you've never interacted with it before. The only way you can get a "user" is if you pass an auth token along with the request.

Comment: @ChrisPratt won't AJAX calls from a page on the same site be sending the same http request information?  ([page](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api)) - oh, I see though he wants to *update* the session.  It's possible to create your own HTTP handler to give you the session but yeah, that's probably not advisable.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat: Things like a session id *may* be sent, but it would essentially be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. Web API intentionally disables the session because it's a REST-compliant API, and REST is stateless. Frankly, there's no way that I know of to change a value in the session on your MVC side of things from a Web API controller.

But, your AJAX doesn't *have* to call a Web API, you can just as easily create an MVC controller action that responds to an AJAX request, and you *would* be able to modify the session from there of course. I think that's going to be your only choice really.

Comment: Is this recommended? Or is now the time to sit down and rethink my app's workflow?

Comment: Perhaps both. There's nothing wrong with creating endpoints for AJAX calls in a normal MVC controller. Just because you're going to be doing some AJAX doesn't mean you *have* to start using Web API. In fact, people go a little overboard with Web API. It's intended to actually create full stack APIs - think Twitter, Facebook, etc. If you're just going to be doing some simple typical website AJAX stuff, it's probably overkill anyways.